# How do I convert a directory to a package in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I'm setting up a Cucumber + Java project with the following project structure:

[image: Project structure]

My configuration correctly maps the main class, feature folder and glue is mapped to "stepdefs".

However, when trying to run the tests, I'll get the Cucumber's "Step undefined" message:

```
Step undefined
You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:
@Given("user is on the homepage")
public void user_is_on_the_homepage() {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
}
```

I noticed the class name in `Steps.java` file is highlighted and complaining that **"Step definition class must be in named package"**:

[image: Step definition class must be in named package]

I tried just adding `package stepdefs` to the top of the file, but that doesn't seem to work ("stepdefs" will be underlined and with note **"Package name 'stepdefs' does not correspond to the file path ''"**).

**UPDATE:**

After some suggestions from @tashkhisi here is my new project structure:

[image]

Comment: The directory has to be inside a source folder to be a package. If you mark the parent folder as a source directory and turn it blue, it should be detected as a package

Comment: You are right! But I'm still getting "Undefined scenarios" from Cucumber.

Comment: I think .feature file should be under resources directory, by the way you can use maven archetype which create best directory structure for you. follow this link: https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/

Comment: @tashkhisi Feature is under resources, and I followed tips for the directory structure, but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

First following link is very useful for getting started with cucumber I suggest you to follow that link for better explanation.

[Getting started with Cucumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409146/cucumber-testing-java-example/62343239#62343239)

But Here this should be your directory structure
I suggest you to use conventional name but if you are determined to do that do this:
mark stepsdef as Test Source Root directory

**UPDATE:**

your main directory must be test and not main.

Where is the @RunWith(Cucumber.class) annotatioon for running your test?

Why don't you use following command to create the best directory structure?

Inside java and resource you shoud have the same directory structure

```
mvn archetype:generate                      \
   "-DarchetypeGroupId=io.cucumber"           \
   "-DarchetypeArtifactId=cucumber-archetype" \
   "-DarchetypeVersion=5.6.0"               \
   "-DgroupId=hellocucumber"                  \
   "-DartifactId=hellocucumber"               \
   "-Dpackage=hellocucumber"                  \
   "-Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"                 \
   "-DinteractiveMode=false"
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please put new directory structure and complete error that you see

Comment: See updated OP for the new dir structure. The complete error is already given. "Step undefined ..." After that there are just the skipped steps, nothing more and nothing before.

Comment: How do you run your  test in your code? there is no class with @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
 annotation and inside java and resource you shoud have the same directory structure see my structure Please!